# How To Solve App Store Connect Organizer Warning "Your version of iTMSTransporter will be updated in approximately ... days" Error?

Tags: ios, testflight, xcode13, macos-monterey, xcode-organizer

I have uploaded a build through the xCode organizer and It shows the error "Your version of iTMSTransporter will be updated in approximately ... days"

As it shows, Upload the archive with warnings thought it was not available in the App Store Connect TestFlight after some time. And there is no any mail received from Apple regarding the build. Any idea how to sort this out and how to upload the build?

This start to happen after I update the macOS to 12.1 Monterey and xCode to 13.
[image]

Comment: How about 'update your version of iTMSTransporter' and test it?

Comment: @blurfus It does not show any new update. Do you know how to update it?

Comment: it tells you in the second notice that you could *"Specify `-updateChannel earlyAccess` on the command line to test it out"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple just released version 13.2.1 that fixes the multiple big issues with 13.2

Answer (score 1):

I have tried a few options but the optimal workaround is to download the iTMSTransporters' early access versions as mentioned in the instructions. You can download it from a terminal command.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter -updateChannel earlyAccess
```

Comment: is it necessary to manually do this or just wait for it to happen?

Answer (score 1):

Ignore this warning and update latest Xcode and it should be gone

Answer (score 1):

Update your XCode to the latest version - Version 13.2.1 (13C100).
Rebuild your solution and upload your app again. The error should not appear anymore.